# Make React Properties not Tied to Specific Variables

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a group of react elements through a for loop. However, it seems that, rather than each element getting its own copy of the variables per for loop, they are tied to whatever the variable is at the end of the for loop (where i = 3). How can I prevent this. Thanks.

```
makeCheckboxes() {
    var checkboxes = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.props.flagNames.length; i++) {
        console.log("Making checkbox. i = " + i);
        checkboxes.push((
            <React.Fragment>
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="reportFlags" value="fraud" checked={this.state.reportFlags[i]} onClick={() => this.handleCheck(i)}/>{this.props.flagNames[i]} </label><br />
            </React.Fragment>
        ));
    }
    return checkboxes;
};
```

Comment: Use 'let' instead of 'var'. 
'Let' is block-scope.
see here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750447/let-keyword-and-closures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace

`for(var i = 0; i < this.props.flagNames.length; i++) {`

by

`for(let i = 0; i < this.props.flagNames.length; i++) {`

actually it will create a closure, so it should sove the problem

if you still want to use `var` you can change your code like this using  immediately-invoked function expression `iife`

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.props.flagNames.length; i++) {
    console.log("Making checkbox. i = " + i);
    checkboxes.push((
        <React.Fragment>
            <label>
               <input 
                  type="checkbox" 
                  name="reportFlags" 
                  value="fraud" 
                  checked={this.state.reportFlags[i]} 
                  onClick={((j) => () => this.handleCheck(j))(i)} //here is the iife
               />
               {this.props.flagNames[i]} 
            </label><br />
        </React.Fragment>
    ));
}
return checkboxes;
```